# Guardar en Base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un archivo .excel con estos datos:
s1 22/02/19 00:00 12 34 56
s1 22/02/19 01:00 12 34 56
s1 22/02/19 02:00 12 34 56
s1 22/02/19 03:00 12 34 56

y asi hasta las 23:00 horas.
lo que necesito es guardar esos datos en un base de datos y luego con una cosulta que me devuelva el dia y con las horas de ese dia representar los datos 12 34 56(que sería diferentes para cada hora) en una gráfica de 3 lineas
la coordenada x seria la hora y la y serian los datos.
alguna sugerencia como se deberían hacer las tablas de la base de datos Sql usando php

Comment: ¿Que has intentado?

Comment: Nada, porque para guardar datos con, por ejemplo, 2 tablas si lo se, pero de esta manera no se me ocurre nada

Comment: ¿Todo lo tienes en una celda?

Comment: En celdas diferentes

Answer (score 0):

Primero hay que entender que MySQL suele trabajar con el formato YYYY-MM-DD, a partir de ahí tendrías que darle formato a la fecha como se muestra en MySQL para ser aceptada, después de eso crear la consulta `SELECT DATEFORMAT(campo1, d%) AS Dia, DATEFORMAT(campo1, %H) as Hora FROM table1`